# Retain raw JSON as column in Spark DataFrame on read/load?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been looking for a way to add my raw (JSON) data as a column when reading my data into a Spark DataFrame.  I have one way to do this with a join but am hoping there is a way to do this in a single operation using Spark 2.2.x+.

So for example data:

```
{"team":"Golden Knights","colors":"gold,red,black","origin":"Las Vegas"}
{"team":"Sharks","origin": "San Jose", "eliminated":"true"}
{"team":"Wild","colors":"red,green,gold","origin":"Minnesota"}
```

When executing:

```
val logs = sc.textFile("/Users/vgk/data/tiny.json") // example data file
spark.read.json(logs).show
```

Predictably we get:

```
+--------------+----------+--------------------+--------------+
|        colors|eliminated|              origin|          team|
+--------------+----------+--------------------+--------------+
|gold,red,black|      null|           Las Vegas|Golden Knights|
|          null|      true|            San Jose|        Sharks|
|red,green,gold|      null|           Minnesota|          Wild|
|red,white,blue|     false|District of Columbia|      Capitals|
+--------------+----------+--------------------+--------------+
```

What I'd like to have on initial load is the above, but with the raw JSON data as an additional column.  For example (truncated raw values):

```
+--------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|        colors|eliminated|              origin|          team|               value|
+--------------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|red,white,blue|     false|District of Columbia|      Capitals|{"colors":"red,wh...|
|gold,red,black|      null|           Las Vegas|Golden Knights|{"colors":"gold,r...|
|          null|      true|            San Jose|        Sharks|{"eliminated":"tr...|
|red,green,gold|      null|           Minnesota|          Wild|{"colors":"red,gr...|
+--------------+----------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

A non-ideal solution involves a join:

```
val logs = sc.textFile("/Users/vgk/data/tiny.json")
val df = spark.read.json(logs).withColumn("uniqueID",monotonically_increasing_id)
val rawdf = df.toJSON.withColumn("uniqueID",monotonically_increasing_id)
df.join(rawdf, "uniqueID")
```

Which results in the same dataframe as above but with and added `uniqueID` column.  Additionally, the json is rendered from the DF and is not necessarily the "raw" data.  In practice they are equal, but for my use case the actual raw data is preferable.

Is anyone aware of a solution that will capture the raw JSON data as an additional column on load?

Comment: Another non-ideal solution is to do an inline conversion from `Row` to its JSON representation. This is probably easier and more reliable.

Comment: I should add that data is heterogeneous and does not conform to a durable schema.  Also, downstream processing would prefer to be passed the unmodified, original json value rather than a produced block based on the data.

Comment: Yes. You could use the rdd api and  map to a new row object with all columns as well as a new text field with the json representation of the entire row. Using something like jackson should do this.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a schema of the data that you receive, then you can use `from_json` with `schema` to get all the fields and keep the `raw` field as it is

```
val logs = spark.sparkContext.textFile(path) // example data file

val schema = StructType(
  StructField("team", StringType, true)::
  StructField("colors", StringType, true)::
  StructField("eliminated", StringType, true)::
  StructField("origin", StringType, true)::Nil
)

logs.toDF("values")
    .withColumn("json", from_json($"values", schema))
    .select("values", "json.*")

    .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+----------+---------+
|values                                                                  |team          |colors        |eliminated|origin   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+----------+---------+
|{"team":"Golden Knights","colors":"gold,red,black","origin":"Las Vegas"}|Golden Knights|gold,red,black|null      |Las Vegas|
|{"team":"Sharks","origin": "San Jose", "eliminated":"true"}             |Sharks        |null          |true      |San Jose |
|{"team":"Wild","colors":"red,green,gold","origin":"Minnesota"}          |Wild          |red,green,gold|null      |Minnesota|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+----------+---------+
```

Hope his helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, the source data is a log stream and the schema is not defined.  Additionally, new attributes can be added or removed from the log lines in the stream at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `to_json` *inbuilt function* in combination with `.withColumn` function as

```
val logs = sc.textFile("/Users/vgk/data/tiny.json")
val df = spark.read.json(logs)
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("value", to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*))).show(false)
```

**Or** even better, not to use `sparkContext`'s `textFile` to read as `rdd`, just use `sparkSession` *to read the json file* as

```
val df = spark.read.json("/Users/vgk/data/tiny.json")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("value", to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col): _*))).show(false)
```

and you should get

```
+--------------+----------+---------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|colors        |eliminated|origin   |team          |value                                                                   |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|gold,red,black|null      |Las Vegas|Golden Knights|{"colors":"gold,red,black","origin":"Las Vegas","team":"Golden Knights"}|
|null          |true      |San Jose |Sharks        |{"eliminated":"true","origin":"San Jose","team":"Sharks"}               |
|red,green,gold|null      |Minnesota|Wild          |{"colors":"red,green,gold","origin":"Minnesota","team":"Wild"}          |
+--------------+----------+---------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This does seem to work, although the stated goal of retaining the original raw data (vs. regenerating it through some mechanism) is still a hurdle.  I suspect this mechanism will be more performant than the uniqueID & join technique - some testing should verify.  If that is the case, which I suspect, then we have still moved forward.

Comment: I didnt understand the meaning of your comment @reverend

Comment: Put another way, rather than needing to put the json back together again via either `toJSON` or `to_json` simply dump the raw data into a column during the read step.  Using toJSON/to_json, which effectively reverses parsing the raw json into the DataFrame, seems to needlessly increase the compute power needed to keep the raw data in a column.  It is an unusual use case, so trying to optimize as much as possible.

Comment: then just read it as text json dataframe . that should have you one column with the json strings in it.

Comment: True, but then how to reverse the solution?  Converting an `RDD[String]` or `Dataset[String]` to JSON results in a new Dataset/DataFrame that then needs to be joined back to the original `Dataset[String]`.  Here again, heterogeneous data w/o a consistent schema does not allow the json functions to be useful for this case.

Comment: why would you want to join the json dataframe to original dataframe.? You are making me more confused

Comment: The use case here, crudely, is part of a streaming pipeline where the ingested json will have some analysis performed upon it and, depending on the results, the original json is passed along for other operations (e.g. alerting, logging, analytics, etc.).  So, the DataFrame extracted from the data is used to determine to where the raw data will be sent to.

Comment: can I be of any help on that. I guess the answer is already been answered. isn't it? so would you mind accepting it and upvoting

Answer (score 1):

Use an rdd mapper to read each line, and manipulate the string to add the raw line in to the json strings, then parse that rdd in to a dataframe json reader.

```
def addRawToJson(line):
    line = line.strip()
    rawJson = line.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"')
    linePlusRaw = f'{line[0:len(line)-1]}, "{RAW_JSON_FIELD_NAME}":"{rawJson}"' + '}'
    return linePlusRaw
    
rawAugmentedJsonRdd = sc.textFile('add file path here').map(addRawToJson)
df = spark.read.json(rawAugmentedJsonRdd)
```

This takes the original json rather than rebuilding it, and does not need to read the data twice and merge it, and it does not need you to know the schema in advance.

Note that my answer is in python using pyspark, but should be easy to change to use scala.

Also note that the method assumes simple single line json input and does not test for valid json before directly manipulating the string, which was acceptable for my usecase.